# Node js passport numeros en NaN

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, passport

Estoy trantando de recibir datos desde un post, no tengo problema con las cadenas, pero cuando mi función recibe un número me la tira en consola cono NaN

```
<select  name="role" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">

                <option value="2">Becario</option>
                <option value="3">Donante</option>
```

ese es parte de mi form, el cual apunta a todo esto:

```
router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local.signup',{
    succesRedirect: '/porfile',
    falureRedirect : '/signup',
    failureFlash : true
}));


const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const pool = require('../../db');

passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'name',
    passwordField : 'pass',
    passReqToCallback : true
}, async (req,name,pass,mail,role,done) => {
   //console.log(req.body);
    const newUser = {
        name,
        pass,
        mail,
        role : parseInt(role)

    };
    console.log([newUser]);
    //await pool.query('Insert into Users set ?',[newUser]);

}));
```

y esto obtengo en consola.

```
[ { name: 'xoxx',
    pass: 'refds',
    mail: [Function: verified],
    role: NaN } ]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: si le quito el parse y paso el puro 'role' me dice que es undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en que el `value` de tus `option` los pasas así: `option value="'1'"`.

Debes quitarle la comilla simple, así: `option value="1"`

La función parseInt() consigue primero la comilla simple al intentar convertir el string en entero y te devuelve NaN

Otra cosa es verificar que realmente estás recibiendo `role` porque si `role` es `undefined` entonces `parseInt` también devuelve NaN.

**Edición:**

Veo un error que no había notado antes. En las opciones que pasas al constructor de LocalStrategy, no estás declarando `role`, tampoco declaras `email`.

En la documentación de `passport-local` encontrarás la información relacionada con las opciones https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local.

Supongamos que recibes `role` desde `req.body.role`, entonces debes usarlo así:

```js
passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'name',
    passwordField : 'pass',
    passReqToCallback : true
}, async (req,name,pass,done) => {
   // He quitado 'mail' y 'role', ya que en las opciones
   // de LocalStrategy solo recibe 'usernameField' y
   // 'passwordField'
   //vemos lo que contiene 'req.body'
    console.log('req.body: ', req.body);
   
    const newUser = {
        name,
        pass,
        mail: req.body.mail ? req.body.mail : '',
        role: req.body.role ? parseInt(req.body.role), 1
        // aqui he usado el operador (?:) para verificar
        // que 'req.body' contiene un campo 'mail' y
        // un campo 'role', si no lo tiene uso
        // uno por defecto, pero es bueno que manejes
        // esos casos en tu código
    }
    
    // vemos el contenido de 'newUser'
    console.log('newUser: ', newUser);
    
    //Aqui va el resto de tu código...
    
    }
  )
 );
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: si usando comillas dobles y quitando el simples me devuelve lo mismo

Comment: Entonces no estás recibiendo `role`.Verifica del lado cliente si realmente estás enviando el valor de `role`

Comment: si cuando lo checo por mi terminal de chrome si lo resivo como parametro, role = 2

Comment: Por favor revisa la edición en mi respuesta, hice una corrección que puede ser de utilidad. Lee bien la documentación de `passport-local`, estás pasando opciones (`mail` y `role`) que no son admitidas o no han sido declaradas.